# vxworks 6.9 pcpentium pcpentium4 bootloader build error

Tags: bootloader, vxworks, x86

I'm trying to create a bootloader/bootrom using the pcpentium/pcpentium4 BSP included with VxWorks 6.9.

I started by creating a boot loader project in workbench using the pcpentium/pcpentium4 BSPs with a GNU compiler to build an uncompressed ELF image which I can use to install on a generic Intel processor based PC.

When I try to build it, I get the error below complaining about the VX_COPROCS_ALL_TASK being undeclared, however I couldn't find where that is defined. Does anyone else have this problem and how did you resolve it?

> In file included from C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.9/target/src/config/usrWdb.c:193,
>                    from C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.9/target/src/config/usrExtra.c:630,
>                    from C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.9/target/config/all/usrConfig.c:612:
>   C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.9/target/config/comps/src/usrWdbSys.c: In function 'wdbSp':
>   C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.9/target/config/comps/src/usrWdbSys.c:116: error: '**VX_COPROCS_ALL_TASK**' undeclared (first use in this function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WIND_BASE\target\h\arch\ppc\coprocPpc.h you should have the following:

```
/* 
modification history
-------------------- 
01c,15may12,jmp  CQID: Fix WIND00309977 : Added VX_COPROCS_ALL_TASK
                  definition.

 [...]

#define VX_COPROCS_ALL_TASK VX_FP_TASK | VX_ALTIVEC_TASK | VX_SPE_TASK
```

Try updating to the latest patch (6.9.4.2 I believe at time of writing).